# Potential null pointer access in Eclipse - seemingly trivial example

Tags: java, eclipse, pointers, null

I have this *very basic piece of code* and Eclipse gives me the "potential null pointer access" warning/error.

```
public class PotentialNull {
    public void test(final String nullableString) {
        boolean isNotNull = nullableString != null;

        if (nullableString != null) {
            // No problem
            System.out.print(nullableString.hashCode());
        }

        if (isNotNull) {
            // Potential null pointer access: The variable nullable may be null at this location
            System.out.print(nullableString.hashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the example, the compiler knows that inside the first if statement, `nullableString` can't be null. However, in the second it doesn't and I really wouldn't have thought this would be too tough to figure out.

Can someone please confirm that this is not specific to my system/setup?

I know, I could suppress warnings etc. but I'm really wondering whether this might be a bug. Or am I overlooking something?

[Another question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687820/potential-null-pointer-access) seems to address a much more complex situation so I hope it's ok I'm asking again.

Comment: Make `isNotNull` `final`. I suspect it thinks that `isNotNull` could be changed in between the declaration and use.

Comment: ...although as it's a local and there's no code changing it, Eclipse should be smart enough to know it's not changed...

Comment: Does the first case still work if you make `nullableString` non-final?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's fundamentally an Eclipse bug report, rather than an answerable SO question.

Comment: what happens if you replace isNotNull with its definition (nullableString != null) ?

Comment: Thanks Andy, but neither making `isNotNull` *final* nor making `nullableString` *not final* changes anything.

Comment: @Gernot That's what I have done in the first if statement in line 5. If I (also) replace it in the second if statement then there is no error. I'd like to keep using a boolean though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is described in Eclipse bug [260293](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=260293) one of several duplicates closed as Won't Fix.

The bug basically says that Eclipse does not track the correlation between the variables `isNotNull` and `nullableString` so it doesn't know that the value can't be null.

Comment: At least I know now that it's actually a bug and I didn't overlook something fundamental. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score -4):

use conditional operator while assigning the boolean varaible isNotNull.
change the line

```
boolean isNotNull = nullableString != null;
```

to

```
boolean isNotNull = (if(nullableString != null)?True:False);
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, it doesn't change anything. Why do you think it works?

Comment: Thanks Isaac, but this doesn't seem to be Java code. Even if I do `boolean isNotNull = nullableString != null ? true : false`, it doesn't change anything.